# google finance Stock ticker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-finance

I am trying to get the stock details from google finance using the following code.

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
var gstock=["INDEXBOM:SENSEX","SHA:000001"];
$(document).ready(function(){
for( var i=0;i<gstock.length;i++){
  $.getJSON("https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=".gstock[i]."&callback=?",function(response){
    var stockInfo = response[0];
    var stockString ='<div class="stockWrapper">STOCK:';
    stockString +='<span class="stockSymbol">'+stockInfo.t+'</span>';
    stockString +='<span class="stockPrice">'+stockInfo.l+'</span>';
    stockString +='<span class="stockChange">'+stockInfo.c+'</span>';
    stockString +='<span>at</span> <span class="stockTime">'+stockInfo.ltt+'</span>';
    stockString +='</div>';
    $('.stockTick').prepend(stockString);
  });
 }
});
</script>
<div class="stockTick"></div>
```

Here when I hardcode the stock exchange details it work.. for example if i put `INDEXBOM:SENSEX` instead of gstock[i] in the getJSON url it works. But i need to get the data of more than 1 stock exchange but i get an error that `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string` in the getJson line. I am not getting what the error is. May be a small one which i didnt notice. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: **Note that if your application is for [public consumption, using the Google Finance API is against Google's terms of service](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-finance-apis/O8fjsgnamHE/-ZKSjif4yDIJ).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use '+' to concatenate string in javascript, not '.'.

```
"...?client=ig&q="+gstock[i]+"&callback=?"
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BejFB/)